# werf docker директивы

Tags: docker, kubernetes, werf

Пытаюсь найти можно ли в werf реализовать докер директиву STOPSIGNAL. В документации нашел только этот список поддерживаемых директив:

```
docker:
  USER: string
  WORKDIR: string
  VOLUME: [ string, ... ]
  ENV: { name string: value string, ... }
  LABEL: { name string: value string, ... }
  EXPOSE: [ string, ... ]
  ENTRYPOINT: string
  CMD: string
  HEALTHCHECK: string
```

Есть ли или планируется ли поддержка директивы STOPSIGNAL?
Или может быть есть возможность вызвать её уже в kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл коммит, в котором STOPSIGNAL был удалён https://github.com/werf/werf/commit/eae15a919a2a50abfa69b0c1001e8d021fc33d82 по причине возникающей ошибки "stopsignal is not a valid change command".

Думаю проблема где-то в механике работы сборщика stapel, которая использует docker commit + опцию `--change` для применения инструкций секции `docker` из werf.yaml. Команда `STOPSIGNAL` по каким-то причинам не поддерживается в docker commit, хотя в теории могла бы поддерживаться.

Открыл issue в werf https://github.com/werf/werf/issues/3094, т.к. данный вопрос требует обдумывания.